# Map Service Tile Cache: ArcGIS Server 10.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, tiles, cache

If I delete my old map services, will the associated Map Service Tile Cache be deleted as well?

For some reason the Map Server Delete Tile Cache tool is not working for me, and our tiles are cached to our server at this moment.  We need to make space on the server for new services, so I am affraid to delete the old services and have their tile cache remain on the server.

Am I safe to just delete the old services? Or is there a way to access the cache in the server manually so I can delete it before proceeding?

Comment: to clarify: Our services' properties have cache directory greyed out... Therefore there is no way to move the location of the cache; and the Delete Cache tool is greyed out as well, therefore we don't even have the option to delete the cache.  My only option now is to delete the service itself, or find out another way to delete the cache by going into the server? Unless the cache will delete along with the service...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the caches are not deleted.

Once you delete the service you can delete the caches.

To locate the caches you can edit the "service" before deleting and the final tab (caching) at the top shows you the location shows you the cache location.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
The only issue is that the cache directory is greyed out, like yours is in the screenshot. So the end of that cache location is cutoff and I can't seem to locate it!

Comment: But now I know that the cache just sits there, so thank you. I was wondering why resources were still maxed... Our datasets are massive, so even one service cache lingering is certainly noticeable!

Comment: The Parameters tab will show you the full location.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I figured out how to access the directories folder through the VPN.